# Keyboard shortcut for change user in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd really like to be able to hit Windows+U to activate the 'change user' function.

Is it remotely possible?

Comment: What edition of Vista do you have? Home, Business or Ultimate?

Comment: @Dennis, Home..

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut for `C:\Windows\System32\tsdiscon.exe` and right click `properties - shortcut` and enter a `shortcut key`

Comment: Only works with Business and Ultimate. Home (both Basic and Premium) don't come with `tsdiscon.exe`.

Comment: @dennis good to know, I was unaware of that. If OP can get his hands on tsdiscon.exe and drops it in place, it will work won't it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would violate the EULA. But [here](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2008/01/17/shortcut-to-switch-user-in-windows-vista/)'s a link to a file that does basically the same thing (untested).